# Map not loading in android

Tags: android, dictionary

Hi I am new to this map in android. I tried to load in my application. I have done everything

1. Generating akey
2. Permissions in manifest file.But only a plain grey grid is coming.

I searched around this half a day. and did whatever they say. everything is correct..But i dont know y the map is not loading..I am really worried about this..Please help me ..Thanks in advance.

My command to generate MD5 FInger print:

```
keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\.android\debug.keystore"\ -storepass android -keypass android
```

My manifest file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.map"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_GSERVICES" />

    <application



        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Mapcctivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_mapcctivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

My activity file:

```
public class Mapcctivity extends MapActivity {
    private MapView mMapView = null;  
     private MapController mc = null;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

//        mMapView = new MapView(this, "0FTpADSJRjSkczl5Jd4E8yoTlhthq6np5gPQClQ");
        setContentView(R.layout.ssss);

//        MapView mp=new MapView(this,"0FTpADSJRjSmVNLeQhafHG_AHJD9mo5lAEsJ_KQ");

        GeoPoint gPoint = new GeoPoint(19240000,-99120000);

        mMapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mMapView.setSatellite(true);
        mMapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        mc = mMapView.getController();
        mc.setZoom(15);
        mc.setCenter(gPoint);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }


}
```

My Layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:apiKey="My generated key"
/>
```

When map is loading my logcat is as follows:

```
12-04 09:42:09.553: E/ActivityThread(285): Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings
12-04 09:42:09.563: E/ActivityThread(285): Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings
12-04 09:42:09.673: E/ActivityThread(285): Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings
12-04 09:42:10.583: D/dalvikvm(285): GC freed 1891 objects / 125528 bytes in 140ms
12-04 09:42:11.213: I/MapActivity(285): Handling network change notification:CONNECTED
12-04 09:42:11.213: E/MapActivity(285): Couldn't get connection factory client
12-04 09:42:12.093: D/dalvikvm(285): GC freed 4623 objects / 271376 bytes in 149ms
12-04 09:42:16.403: D/dalvikvm(285): GC freed 13753 objects / 921216 bytes in 175ms
12-04 09:42:26.873: D/dalvikvm(285): GC freed 9400 objects / 642912 bytes in 181ms
```

Please help me to solve this..

Comment: Everything looks good in your code. The problem might be because of the API key. Try to regenerate it again because you may done mistake while registering it or something. But after going through your code it seems to be the API key related issue. For more detail please refer this link. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/hello-mapview

Comment: Thanks  Scorpion ..But i generated key a lot of times...But still i am getting the same error..For getting fingerprint ..i have to use the above command only right..or otherwise i have to do someother thing??

Comment: command is right. Ok then check you selected Google API not Android while creating project. Also which version of api you are using? 4.0.3?

Comment: try to run your project in device

Comment: Scorpion i am using Google API version 7..

Comment: try using the Google API Level 10+ if you have the latest versions with you. ICS or gingerbread.

Comment: Scorpion..k i will try that..But whats the problem in this API level 7..

Comment: you are running it in emulator or real device? If on emulator I think there is issue in showing maps on api 7 but I am not sure for that. So i suggested you to use higher api version.

Comment: oh k k..Actually i am running in emulator..

Comment: @Subburaj Are you using google api emulator or simple api emulator?

Comment: i think some error in geo points please try with other points...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all dude..I get solved this..Really i vexed after i finding the solution..

The problem is :

See in my manifest file permission..`For "INTERNET" i misspelled as "INERNET"`...This culprit is the problem..

Answer (score 0):

Generate map key as follow:

1.[Go to this link and generate MD5 fingerprint](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/mapkey)

2.[Click on this link you will get map key using generated MD5 fingerprint](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/maps-api-signup)

3.Use this key in your xml file.

Comment: I check your manifest ,there is problem with your internet premisson  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INERNET" / > check this you have misspelled INTERNT

Answer (score 0):

set

```
 android:minSdkVersion="8"
```

in your manifest.

Comment: I am sorry. i forgot to change it to 8 in my post.try changing it to 8.